# Border Image gif doesn't animate for svg in Edge 42

Tags: html, css, svg, microsoft-edge

I am using a gif file to show animated border using css `border-image` around a svg element.

```css
#animated-gif-container {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-image: url(https://s3.gifyu.com/images/practiceHighlighBorder.gif) 2 round;
}
```

```html
<svg id="animated-gif-container"></svg>
```

This works well in Chrome, Firefox, but not in Edge (Version 42)

Verified it is working in Edge 20 also. Verified it works for div element also. However I can not change it to div because of dependency in code.

One interesting thing, if I select element by dev tool, image starts animating. Not able to figure out the solution

[image]

URL to reproduce: https://plnkr.co/edit/IeVQf7mjTJuPdwFckumf?p=preview

Comment: [report it as a bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/) to Microsoft

Comment: Reported to microsoft also now: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/21713223/

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to use an image to achieve this effect. Source for my answer [is a talk from Lea Verou.](https://youtu.be/vs34f9FiHps?t=786)

Note if you run this here on the site it won't work, you would have to encode it. I chose to keep it more readable but to see the effect in action you have to include the CSS-part in a referenced stylesheet (e.g. styles.css) instead of just putting it into the head of your site.

```css
. {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml,\
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">\
   <style> @keyframes ants {to {stroke-dashoffset: -15px;}} </style>\
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 4px; fill: none;\
    stroke-dasharray: 10px 5px; animation: ants .4s infinite linear;" /> \
  </svg>');
}
```

```html
<div class="" contenteditable> Look at my awesome border</div>
```